# Recursive function to convert coin amount into quarters, dimes, nickles, pennies

Tags: java, recursion, modulo

I have a little project that converts an amount of coins into their respective quarter, dime, nickel, penny amounts. The basic idea was this:

```
public static void coinCombo() {
    int amount = getInt();
    int quarter_cnt = amount/QUARTER;
    int r1 = amount%QUARTER;
    int dime_cnt = r1/DIME;
    int r2 = r1%DIME;
    int nickel_cnt = r2/NICKEL;
    int r3 = r2%NICKEL;
    System.out.println("Quarters: " + quarter_cnt);
    System.out.println("Dimes: " + dime_cnt);
    System.out.println("Nickels: " + nickel_cnt);
    System.out.println("Pennies: " + r3);
}
```

However, this looks rather bulky to me. I would like to know how to do this recursively. I see that I use the remainder of the previous operation to get the next one. I feel that this can be done more concisely. Can someone provide an example of a recursive way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do it like this.

```
static final int[] den = {25,10,5,1};
static final String[] names = {"Quarters", "Dimes","Nickels", "Pennies"};

public static void coinCombo(int amount) {
     for (int i = 0; i < den.length; i++) {
         System.out.printf("%s: %d%n", names[i], amount/den[i]);
         amount %= den[i];
     }
}

coinCombo(119);
```

Prints

```
Quarters: 4
Dimes: 1
Nickels: 1
Pennies: 4
```

Note that the above could easily be modified to include larger denominations (`$10`, `$5`, and `$1` bills).

But here is your recursive solution.  It requires one more argument.

```
coinCombo(232,0);

public static void coinCombo(int amount, int i) {
    if (amount > 0) {
        System.out.printf("%s: %d%n", names[i], amount/den[i]); 
        coinCombo(amount % den[i], i+1);
    }
}
```